# IBoutlet , 2 Different ways to Write?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, iboutlet

I am new to iPhone OS App development. Can somebody explain whats the difference between

```
IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;

As far i understand the first line was used earlier and now we can use the 2nd line. Theres absolutely no need to write both of them. Any idea?

Taimur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just write `IBOutlet` in the @property declaration.  It won't hurt to put it in both spots though.

You're not asking the difference between the whole lines though are you?

Comment: Yeah thats what i wanted to confirm , do we need to write it at both points.

Comment: You only need `IBOutlet` in the `@property` declaration but both lines are still necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Apple now recommends that you only put the `IBOutlet` declaration on the `@property`.